# Deploying Django on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to host a Python\Django app on Heroku. I followed the guide on heroku website but when I execute the line "heroku ps:scale web:1" it comes back the following message:

> No process types on ⬢ salty-brushlands-45215.
>    ▸    Upload a Procfile to add process types.
>    ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

I already tryed to commit a Procfile into my project (searching for a solution) but I don't know if requires any configuration inside it. Help please!

Comment: what is inside your Procfile?

Comment: add  your Profile code content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Procfile should contain this,

```
web: gunicorn your_project.wsgi
```

web defines the type of your application

gunicorn is a wsgi server

Comment: "The file name should start with a dot .i,e The file name should be .Procfile"—this is incorrect. [The file should be named exactly `Procfile`, and have no extension](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location).

Answer (score 0):

1.Create .txt file.

2.add this raw to your file:

```
worker: python main.py
```

3.save file and delete file extension (.txt)

4.add Procfile to master folder

5.deploy